# Regex not working for site redirects in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all URIs to "bar" unless the URI is "foo"

So far I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!\/foo$).*
RewriteRule .* /bar [L]
```

When I try to access "10.0.1.3/foo" I get redirected to "10.0.1.3/bar".  I want it to stay at "10.0.1.3/foo".

I looked at other answers for similar problems on this site and for some reason I still am always redirected.  Does apache need to be rebooted to read the new htaccess file?  I didn't think it did....

I use http://regexr.com/ to test out my expressions and it seems like this regex is that way to go.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Apache's regex engine is simple, and uses `!` for negation, so you probably only need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo`

Comment: how is it "simple"?  Does it use a different version of regex?  Since my testing tool was wrong, I'd like to know another way to test out my regex because I put it in htaccess.  But your negation solution was spot on.  It started looping though just as @Jon Lin said it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those rules work for me if I try to go to `/foo`, it doesn't redirect. However, the rules are written in such a way that they loop. If you request for anything other than "/foo", it gets rewritten to `/bar` and then when the engine loops, `/bar` matches the same rule and gets rewritten to `/bar` again. Resulting in a 500 error.

That doesn't address your problem though. The condition is fine. You don't need to reboot for htaccess changes to take effect, tou do need to make sure your apache server is setup to allow htaccess overrides (see `AllowOverride` directive) and that you have mod rewrite loaded.

Comment: Because of the loop I ended up just redirecting the root directory to /bar
Thanks for the tip. ';' = new line:

RewriteEngine On; 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$; 
RewriteRule .* /bar [R=301,L];